# Adding data to remote request in typeahead

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I'm working with typeahead 0.9.3 and I am trying to configure it to consume an ASP.NET WebMethod. I've verified that the web method is working.

I am having trouble configuring typeahead to make a correct request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.search').typeahead([
    {
        name: "site_search",
        remote: {
            url: "/AjaxProxy.aspx/GetTopSearchTerms",
            beforeSend: function (jqXhr, settings) {
                var data = new Object();
                data.term = "test";
                data.count = "5";

                jqXhr.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
                settings.type = 'POST';
                //settings.contentType = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
                settings.data = JSON.stringify(data);
                return true;
            },
            filter: function (data) {
                console.log(data);                    
                return data;
            }
        }            
    }
]);
</script>
```

I have two problems right now that I am not sure are related or not.

1. When I look at the request in developer tools, it is not sending a request payload.
2. It is also not including the Content-Type header but I am not sure if this is due to there being no payload.